# What's wrong here on casting from T?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Here's my [code](http://rextester.com/ETPT71475):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Factory factory = new Factory();
    }           
}     

public class Factory
{
    public Factory() {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        MVCSender<Animal>(animal);                  
    }    

    public void MVCSender<T>(object elem) {
        WebAPIReceiver<T>(elem);
    }   

    public void WebAPIReceiver<T>(object elem) {
        WebAPIProcesser((T)elem);
    }

    public void WebAPIProcesser(Animal elem) {
        elem.Speak();
    } 
}  

public class Animal
{
    public Animal() {}

    public void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal Speak!");
    } 
}
```

I pass the `T` across functions, and on the "endpoints" I try to cast the generic `object` type using the type `T` I've passed across functions.

Its an self-learning question, the whole doesn't make any sense.

1. Why can't I cast `WebAPIProcesser((T)elem)` to `Animal` from `T`?
2. What is the meaning of writing  (after the function name) on generics in C#? Does it simply substitute the `template <class T>` (on `C++` for example) before any function declaration?

Comment: Because `object` isn't a `T` and `T` isn't an `Animal`. Research the compiler errors you get.

Comment: Why are your parameters objects when you already know what T is in order to call them? They can be T elem

Comment: 2.  `public void WebAPIReceiver<T>(T elem) where T : Animal {
        WebAPIProcesser(elem);
    }` is the way to pass T as argument.

Comment: @User.Anonymous still doesn't works http://rextester.com/QAUW36864

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when you make the methods `WebAPIReceiver<T>` and `WebAPIReceiver<T>` generic? What types should be substitutable for `T`? Why will the signature `M(Animal elem)` not suffice for your purpose?

Comment: @markzzz sorry, I was to quickly. Here you can find a working sample to use, invoke and cast T from your code : http://rextester.com/ATHD12819

Comment: But same questions as above, in your case, T is useless.

Comment: @User.Anonymous: unfortunatly is not what I'm trying to emulate. I'm trying understand how a MVC Change rest call such as `SingleRestCall<T>(string baseAPI, object entity)` (where I pass `T` as Animal and `entity` as `object`) can be resolved on the REST service and call automatically `public IHttpActionResult Change(Animal elem)`

Comment: If your need is to call an ApiController of T, then you can't. The solution that reflects the more is to make a generic call as `Get(string type, string entity)` where type is 'Animal' and entity is your JSON definition of model. And so, you can call a base generic SingleRestCall<T>

Comment: @User.Anonymous: If you reply to me with an answer where you show to me how to convert from template `T` to string (i.e. infer Animal to string "Animal") you will get my "accepted" answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
public void WebAPIReceiver<T>(object elem) {
    WebAPIProcesser((T)elem);
}
```

In contrast to C++ templates, that only fail if what you *actually do* with them is illegal, C# makes sure *any* call you *could* make must be legal.

In your case: Although `T` *in your case* is `Animal`, the compiler has to make sure that your method works for *any* `T`. And it does not. It fails for any non-`Animal`. So the compiler will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

> If you reply to me with an answer where you show to me how to convert
>   from template T to string (i.e. infer Animal to string "Animal") you
>   will get my "accepted" answer!

```
void Main()
{
    Foo<Animal> foo = new Foo<Animal>();
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    Console.Write(foo.Get(animal));
}

public class Animal
{
}

public class Foo<T> {

    public string Get(T entity)
    {
        return entity.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but the problem is the other side.  `string type = entity.GetType().Name;` of course its easy to resolve. But when I reach the ApiController, how would you build the object from the string and pass it to a typed method? I mean that's easy `object entity = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);` (with `Type entityType = Type.GetType("" + type);`), but how than pass the `object`to `WebAPIChange(Registration registration)` for example? http://rextester.com/GLDWA23838